# JQuery increase wait time before it throws error in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop-1.7

I would like to be able to increase the waiting time before an error is displayed in my code of this script... but I don't have much idea how to do it...

It is assumed that when opening the modal sometimes it opens very quickly and the server shows an error...

This opening modal is from a gateway in Ecuador...

```
<script>   

$("#content-hook_order_confirmation").addClass("hide");
$("#content-hook_payment_return").addClass("hide");
$('#contenedor').insertBefore('#content');

   var PaymentCheckout = new PaymentCheckout.modal({
            client_app_code: "{$client_app_code}", 
                  client_app_key: "{$client_app_key}", 
            locale: "es", 
            env_mode: "{$ambiente}", 
            onOpen: function() {
                console.log("se abrio modal");
            },
            onClose: function() {
                console.log("cerró modal");
            },
            onResponse: function(response) { 
          
               console.log(response);
              announceTransaction(response);
                if (response.transaction["status_detail"] == 3) {
                   
                   showMessageSuccess();

                } else {
                     showMessageError(); 
                }
             
            }
        });


      
        var btnOpenCheckout = document.querySelector(".Rot");
        var btnOpenCheckoutDifCon = document.querySelector(".DifCon");
        var btnOpenCheckoutDifSin = document.querySelector(".DifSin");
      
        btnOpenCheckout.addEventListener("click", function(){
          
        PaymentCheckout.open({
              user_id: "{$uid}",
              user_email: "{$email}",       
              user_phone: "{$telnumber}",
             order_description: "{$descripcion}",
              order_amount: {$order_amount},
             order_reference: "{$dev_reference}",            
            order_vat: {$vat},            
            order_tax_percentage: {$tax_percentage}, 
            order_taxable_amount: {$taxable_amount} 
            
          });
        });


           btnOpenCheckoutDifCon.addEventListener("click", function(){
          
          PaymentCheckout.open({
            user_id: "{$uid}",
            user_email: "{$email}",       
            user_phone: "{$telnumber}",
            order_description: "{$descripcion}",
            order_amount: {$order_amount},
            order_reference: "{$dev_reference}",            
            order_vat: {$vat},            
            order_tax_percentage: {$tax_percentage}, 
            order_taxable_amount: {$taxable_amount}, 
            order_installments_type: 2,
          });
        });


          btnOpenCheckoutDifSin.addEventListener("click", function(){
          
          PaymentCheckout.open({
            user_id: "{$uid}",
            user_email: "{$email}",       
            user_phone: "{$telnumber}",
            order_description: "{$descripcion}",
            order_amount: {$order_amount},
            order_reference: "{$dev_reference}",            
            order_vat: {$vat},            
            order_tax_percentage: {$tax_percentage}, 
            order_taxable_amount: {$taxable_amount},  
            order_installments_type: 3,
          });
        });

         
        
        window.addEventListener("popstate", function() {
          PaymentCheckout.close();
        });



        function showMessageSuccess() {
          $("#message").addClass("hide");
          $("#buttonspay").addClass("hide");
          $("#messagetwo").removeClass("hide");
                   
        }  


         function showMessageError() {
    
          $("#message").addClass("hide");
          $("#buttonspay").addClass("hide");
          $("#messagetres").removeClass("hide");
          
      }

        function announceTransaction(data) {
            fetch("{$paymentez_hook}", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
            }).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            }).catch(function(myJson) {
            console.log(myJson);
            });
        }

</script>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use setTimeOut function to wait for. An example of this can be

```
setTimeout(function(){
//your code 
},5000)
```

5000 means 5 seconds

Comment: Where in the code do I put that?

Comment: inside your click event and replace your code with //your code comment